# Python Collatz Infinite Loop

Tags: python-3.x, infinite-loop

Apologies if similar questions have been asked but I wasn't able to find anything to fix my issue. I've written a simple piece of code for the Collatz Sequence in Python which seems to work fine for even numbers but gets stuck in an infinite loop when an odd number is enter.

I've not been able to figure out why this is or a way of breaking out of this loop so any help would be greatly appreciate.

```
print ('Enter a positive integer')
number = (int(input()))

def collatz(number):
    while number !=1:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            number = number/2
            print (number)
            collatz(number)
        elif number % 2 == 1:
            number = 3*number+1
            print (number)
            collatz(number)

collatz(number)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function lacks any `return` statements, so by default it returns `None`. You might possibly wish to define the function so it returns how many steps away from `1` the input number is. You might even choose to [cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) such results.

You seem to want to make a recursive call, yet you also use a `while` loop. Pick one or the other.

When recursing, you don't *have* to reassign a variable, you could choose to put the expression into the call, like this:

```
    if number % 2 == 0:
        collatz(number / 2)
    elif ...
```

This brings us the crux of the matter. In the course of recursing, you have created many stack frames, each having its own private variable named `number` and containing distinct values. You are confusing yourself by changing `number` in the current stack frame, *and* copying it to the next level frame when you make a recursive call. In the even case this works out for your termination clause, but not in the odd case. You would have been better off with just a `while` loop and no recursion at all.

You may find that http://pythontutor.com/ helps you understand what is happening.
A power-of-two input will terminate, but you'll see it takes pretty long to pop those extra frames from the stack.

[image: execution trace]

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified the code required to find how many steps it takes for a number to get to zero following the Collatz Conjecture Theory.

```
def collatz():
        steps = 0
        sample = int(input('Enter number: '))
        y = sample

    while sample != 1:
        if sample % 2 == 0:
            sample = sample // 2
            steps += 1

        else:
            sample = (sample*3)+1            
            steps += 1

    print('\n')   
    print('Took '+ str(steps)+' steps to get '+ str(y)+' down to 1.')

collatz()
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Hereafter is my code snippet and it worked perfectly

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def collatz(i):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        n = i // 2
        print n
        if n != 1:
            collatz(n)
    elif i % 2 == 1:
        n = 3 * i + 1       
        print n
        if n != 1:
            collatz(n)
try:
    i = int(raw_input("Enter number:\n"))
    collatz(i)
except ValueError:
    print "Error: You Must enter integer"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my interpretation of the assignment, this handles negative numbers and repeated non-integer inputs use cases as well. Without nesting your code in a while True loop, the code will fail on repeated non-integer use-cases.

```
def collatz(number):
if number % 2 == 0:
    print(number // 2)
    return(number // 2)
elif number % 2 == 1:
    result = 3 * number + 1
    print(result)
    return(result)

# Program starts here.        
while True:
    try:
        # Ask for input
        n = input('Please enter a number: ')
        # If number is negative or 0, asks for positive and starts over.
        if int(n) < 1:
            print('Please enter a positive INTEGER!')
            continue
        #If number is applicable, goes through collatz function.
        while n != 1:
            n = collatz(int(n))
    # If input is a non-integer, asks for a valid integer and starts over.
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a valid INTEGER!')
    # General catch all for any other error.
    else:
        continue
```